# Time complexity of while loop until list is empty?

Tags: performance, loops, time, big-o

My pseudo code is currently constructed as:

```
WHILE list is not empty
   FOR item in list
      do stuff to find an item that matches certain criteria
   REMOVE matching item from list
```

I am having a hard time wrapping my mind about what the time complexity will be due to the fact that after each iteration the list will be getting smaller. Any thoughts? I thought o(n) since there is only 1 for loop per while iteration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be careful. o(n) and O(n) are very different.
2. “Only one for loop per iteration” - that one loop is not constant time, so your argument is wrong.
3. You seem to assume there is always a “matching item” that can be removed. If that isn’t true then your algorithm is fatally flawed.

Unless the criteria to be matched changes when an item is removed, you can make one pass through the loop without starting the search again at the beginning, so this can be done in O(n) where n is the size of the initial list.

Comment: Thank you. The criteria will remain the same throughout the loop, but its basis will change. For each for loop, each element will be compared to another 'comparable' value and the one closest to that value will be the one removed. The 'comparable' value is then changed to the item that was just removed. Therefore I can't just loop through the list one as I have to loop through it multiple times until it is empty and all the closest values are printed one by one.